# Slidemenu and tabbed ViewPager as Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using `Slidemenu` from jfeinstein10's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). I'm currently using the `switchFragment` method from him to exchange the above fragment. The code currently is loosely based on the responsive ui sample.

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    if (getActivity() instanceof BaseActivity) {
        BaseActivity ra = (BaseActivity) getActivity();
        ra.switchContent(fragment);
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I got the idea that each above fragment should have a `viewpager` (everyone with different tabs). Something like this:

[image: Mockup]

So for a `viewpager` I need to convert the fragments to a `FragmentActivity`. What's the best way to do this?

**Edit:**

What have I tried?
First I searched through stackoverflow and through the slidemenu github for similar problems. Then I tried the stupid way to convert the fragments to FragmentActivity and just fix the code (error wise). However I received some nasty errors and somehow the code was ugly afterwards. So I hope someone here with more expertise in Android knows how this could be done more elegantly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't read the FAQ, please [do so now](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This question is on topic, but we would like to see some [effort on your part](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Fixed it. I used intent to start the FragmentActivity and extended the ViewPager with BaseActivity.